# Is it correct to say "I'm in my 24"?

Tags: grammaticality

I just want to know if it could be a correct form, for example, to use when it's someone's birthday.

Comment: We never say that. We might say 'I'm in my 24th year' during the year that **ends** with my 24th birthday. We could say 'I am 24 today' on my 24th birthday.

Comment: I have said "I'm in my 78.", as a joke, when the subject is being in one decade or another. It's a joke because it's not grammatical.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I don't see the joke. Am I just thick?

Comment: @WS2: You and me both, mate! But it really puts me in mind of something from "pop physicist" Brian Greene that I found positively riveting last night. Check out what he says at [1:08.46 in this Youtube discussion about AI.](https://youtu.be/EGDG3hgPNp8?t=4126) He asks chatgpt *If I tell you that 7 times 8 is 62 (not 56) can you come up with **five** strategies of how you could make sense of it?* The way chatgpt constructs at least one plausible "interpretation" there is just mind-boggling! And I use chatgpt every day! (Writing code for me in a programming language I never bothered to learn! :)

Comment: (I take Jack's choice of the specific number **78** and Green's example **7**x**8** as further evidence that the super-advanced chatgpt-type simulation that we're actually *living* in is running out of compute power and re-using / sharing variables more often than it used to! :)

Comment: No it's wrong. It's not grammatical and worse, it doesn't make sense.  Are you perhaps confusing this with something like "I'm in my twenties"?  You can only use this construction with decades: teens, twenties, thirties, forties, etc.

Comment: @WS2 It's a joke because it pokes fun at the coy generality of "in my seventies" with a  specific number, while using a parallel, albeit non-grammatical, structure.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty I'll take your word for it Jack - but for some reason it didn't send me into a paroxysm of thigh-slapping laughter. Perhaps I don't have much of a sense of humour :)

Answer (score 0):

In standard spoken and written English, many prepositions are used with ages. However, "in my 24" makes no sense. It can be rephrased with an ordinal number and the word "year": "I'm in my 24th year."

Here are some common phrases for age:

I am 24.

I am about to be/turn/reach 24.

It's my 24th birthday today/Tuesday/next week.

Comment: I'd even consider `I am in my 24th` as a weirdly affected (but acceptable) response to `how old are you?` but you'd have to be a character in a P.G.Wodehouse novel.

Comment: I am in my 20s is also good, or mid 20s even

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not idiomatic English.

The most common way to state your age is:

> I am 24.

You could say "*I am in my 24th year*" and that would be grammatically correct, but that would mean you are 23, which is just confusing. You only become 24 when you have lived 24 complete calendar years.